# Add in a title to the MeanMenu JQuery Responsive Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am currently using the MeanMenu JQuery plugin to create a responsive navigation for my website and I would like to know how can I add in a title name to the navigation once it's in responsive mode.

My JQuery skills are not that strong and I'm unsure.

Demo: http://www.meanthemes.com/demo/meanmenu/demo.html. View it in responsive, and there's 3 bars on the right that acts as a menu drawer. I would like to add a title next to the bar.

Most of the responsive part of the navigation is written in JQuery, which is something new to me.

Would appreciate some help on this.

`Link:` http://jsfiddle.net/dDRZe/4/

Thank you.

Comment: you can add add <span>Title</span> with properties positioning and display:none in default. And when responsive menu appear span will display: block. Thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe do something like this:

**Javascript**

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 480) {
        $('.mean-bar').before('<div class="myDiv">content</div>');
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.myDiv {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

**Updated simpler solution**

Add to the top of your page:

```
<div class="myDiv">Content</div>
```

CSS to show/hide it:

```
.myDiv {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    .myDiv {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

That will give you a div which you can put whatever title you want onto and style it how you want with CSS.

Comment: I see ok. But where do I write it inside the Jquery. There are various  methods for each part of the navigation. Unsure to which part shall i place it.

Comment: @Jeiman : Have you got your own custom JavaScript file (e.g. myscripts.js)? If not, create one and make sure it is called (in your HTML) AFTER your MeanMenu plugin (and after Jquery), then just put the code I've used into that file and it should work fine

Comment: Alright it sort of works. But the content is above and outisde of the responsive navigation. It's weird how I have to refresh the page in reponsive mode in order to see the Content.

Comment: Also, I did some custom styling to the myDiv in my CSS, the navigation sorts of runs out and when you scroll down in responsive, the navigation is hanging halfway due to the new div taking space at the top of the page, if that makes sense?

Comment: @Jeiman : Please can you post a JSFiddle of your code? Would make things a bit easier for me to help. As a note, you'll probably need to set `position:absolute;` on your new div, and also `position:relative;` on your "mean-bar" container. I've never used MeanMenu before, but if it has a callback function,  then you could add my code there, which would ensure that it is called whenever MeanMenu is run, if that makes sense?

Comment: I have posted the JSfiddle in the question, however its missing out the new js code you sent me due to the reason of it being ran outside of the html file (external JS).

Comment: @Jeiman : Please see update. Update your JS file with my new updated code, and also add the CSS I've added - it's just ta starting point, but should be what you're after.

Comment: Ok, somehow its not working now with the new JS code. Would you mind explaining what does that new line of JS code does to the menu?

Comment: @Jeiman : To be honest, you could completely scrap my JS code - I was just trying to avoid having extra content in your markup. All you need to do is just put a Div right at the top of your page, and just style it with the CSS I provided. Then you can just use a CSS3 media query to show/hide it when the browser is resized under 480px

Comment: @Jeiman : Please see updated simpler solution using no extra JS.

Comment: Hmm I see your point. The new code you gave is logical too. But somehow this new code too is not showing up. It seems that the JQuery is blocking/overriding any new elements that might affect the responsive navigation. Thoughts on this matter?

Comment: @Jeiman : When you state "new code is not showing up" - are you referring to the new div ("MyDiv")? If so, it just needs to be placed just after your opening `<body>` tag, and it should work fine. It will then display when your browser resizes under 480px - there should be nothing wrong with this, as it's as simple as it gets - please can you update your website and I'll take a look and see what's going on.

Comment: Yes your new code and yes I did place the newDiv right below the `body` tag. Not sure what is going on as your code logical should work. Please refer to the updated link in the question.

Comment: @Jeiman : I think I see the issue - the `mean-bar` menu container has a `z-index` value of 999999. This means that it will be on top of your new div. Slightly annoying, but if you set the `z-index` of your new div to be even higher (just add an extra '9'), then that should (hopefully!) solve the problem.

Comment: Yes! It worked! Completely forgot to see the `z-index` value of the container. Thanks alot for your extended help.

Comment: @Jeiman : That's ok, I missed the z-index also - easily done! Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved (IE >= 9)...

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    a.meanmenu-reveal::after {
        content: "menu";
        font-size: 16px;
        position: absolute;
        text-indent: 0;
        left: -40px;
        bottom: 12px;
    }
}
```